# Ads code show blank space or not showing at all

Tags: google-adsense

I am using joomla as a cms and I tried to add AdSense code in a module ( i tried the custom joomla module and also other extensions like ads elite and flexi custom code but none has worked ) and it only shows a blank space where the ad should be.

I thought it was an AdSense issue, so I tried adding code from other ad networks  and they wont show up either.

All the code starts with a `<script>` tag, however I added a code from a PTC site (paid to click ) like neobux.com that starts with `<a href` and it worked just fine.

To be more clear my question is : if you had a joomla website how would you publish ads on it ( from adsense or other ads networks )

Can you help me add those ads code to my website?

Comment: Module? Can you possibly tells us more? What CMS, module, module settings, etc. Otherwise, there is absolutely no way we can answer your question. There is no actionable detail for us to even guess.

Comment: and what is PTC? and also, have you made sure javascript is enabled in your browser that you're testing adsense on? The current adsense code is asynchronous javascript code, but there was the synchronous javascript code that works for older browsers but I'm not sure if it will work with google anymore. Also, try with the basic text-only ads because some enhanced ads will not work for browsers without all the extensions required installed (like flash, HTML5, etc.)

Comment: Please edit this question to provide more information.  Both closetnoc and Mike have asked for clarification.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have JavaScript enabled in your browser like Mike suggested, you haven't deleted browser cache between code edits, or you might have ad blocking software installed. I'd suggest checking with different browsers & devices. Unfortunately individual website troubleshooting is considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: no i did all the above ,,, checked that js is enabled and cleared the cache and disabled adblock ,,, changed even the browser and pc ,,, if you were me how would you add the code ??

Answer (score 1):

Well the probleme I faced was as simple as enabling SSL; It seems that some ad networks serve ads for publishers that can't support SSL, so if your site is encrypted and has HTTPS on its URL ( notice the "S" at the end ) than you wont be able to display those ads.

If you disable SSL on your site than you will be able to display all ads from any ad network, however their are some ad networks like AdSense that can serve ads trough SSl ( HTTPS ) with either a little modification to an old ad code or by creating a new one.

So at the end you must ask yourself if your website needs to be secure and encrypted with SSL ( sites that has critical information like users passwords and snesitive data should always enable SSL ) and in this case use only ad networks that support SSL, other than that if your site is only HTTP than everything should be just OK.

There is of course other reasons why ads do not display ( AdSense don't display ads if your website is new or if it can't find relevant content for their ads ); but in my case that was the probleme.

i hope it can help others solve their issues.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Adsense is when it's first setup, it can be blank for sometime (hours) before ads starts showing. However you should also check your browser's console in case there are any other SSL / Javascript related issues.